# Look up for questions with a score of -1 or lower

Tags: support

I am looking for questions which got downgraded and see why to improve mines. For this, I have searched for "score:-1" but it says "Search options not deleted score>= -1" and that is not what I want. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[score:..-1 is:question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=score%3a..-1%20is%3aquestion)

For more details on advanced search visit [help/searching](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/searching).